# php SOLR как получить документы из SolrQuery?

Tags: php, solr

Значит в мануале есть такой код

```
$client = new SolrClient($options);

$query = new SolrQuery();

$query->setQuery($_GET['q'] ? $_GET['q'] : '*:*');

$query->setStart(0);

$query->setRows(50);

$query->addField('cat')->addField('id');

$query_response = $client->query($query);

$response = $query_response->getResponse();

print_r($response);
```

Все работает. Но как извлечь и получить данные самих документов из **$response**

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам)

```
foreach ($response->response->docs as $d) {
  echo $d->FIELD. " ";
}
```